# making the navigation menu bold

Tags: wordpress

I know this seems to be a stupid question but I have a problem with my navigation menu - I can`t find a way to get the text in the navigation menu bold. I tried and tried to find this out by using firebug but without success.

I`m using wordpress theme "hueman". The website is www.traumbad-muenchen.de.

Thanks so much guyes for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick. Add this to your CSS to bold the links in the navigation.

```
.nav > li {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: If you believe this was the correct answer, please select the "Checkmark" icon next to the answer.